# Error: stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y enen when x and y are defined

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a short example of a data frame I read from a csv file:

```
   entry    Number of sales     Median revenue
1: DN1_01   345                 1556
2: DN1_02   478                 2424
3: DN1_03   111                 450
4: DN1_04   595                 3265
5: DN1_05   446                 162
```

and I'd like to plot it with ggplot2. I run the below script:

```
Figure_8 <- ggplot(figure8_df, aes(x = figure8_df$'number of sales', 
y= figure8_df$'median revenue')) +
geom_point(col = "darkmagenta", shape = 18) + ggtitle("Number of sales 
VS Median revenue") + 
xlab("Number of sales") + ylab("Median revenue") + geom_smooth(method = 'lm') +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color="orange", size=14, face="bold.italic"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(color="#993333", size=10, face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="#993333", size=10,face = "bold")) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty(figure8_df$'median revenue', n = 20))
```

and got the error:

```
Error: stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y
```

But I don't understand what is the problem. I defined in aes x and y, so why do I get this message?

Comment: Try this as first `ggplot` call `ggplot(figure8_df, aes(\`number of sales\`, \`median revenue\`))`. Single quote (`'number of sales'`) turns string to character.

Comment: In addition, according to your sample data the column names start with capital letters. (but I guess that is not the reason for the error)

Comment: Don't use the `$` inside the `aes`